# How do I install zRam?

Tags: installation, 11.10, zram

How can I install zRam on my Ubuntu 11.10 acer inspire netbook? Seems like it would be advantageous to use zRam. And would it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install Zram for Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10:

Open terminal and type in:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shnatsel/zram
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install zramswap-enabler

from:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html

Answer (score 3):

zram is built into the Linux kernel.  I've been experimenting with zram and have a brief script to set it up for swapping, like this:

```
modprobe zram num_devices=2
echo "268435456" > /sys/block/zram0/disksize 
echo "268435456" > /sys/block/zram1/disksize 
mkswap /dev/zram0
mkswap /dev/zram1
swapon -p 1000 /dev/zram0
swapon -p 1000 /dev/zram1
```

The machine I was testing on had 1GB of RAM, so I decided to use 256MB*2 for zram swapping.  You can also use a similar technique to set up zram as an ext3 filesystem.

You can check zram usage by cat'ing /sys/block/zram0/orig_data_size and mem_used_total