# SageMath memory limit

Tags: 16.04, ram, sagemath

I have installed [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/) 8.9 on my Ubuntu 16.04 using the files downloaded from the SageMath site.

While running my script to analyze some data, SageMath threw the error `Condition of type: STORAGE-EXHAUSTED`. After some web search, I found this means SageMath has reached a memory limit.

How do I increase this limit?

The script I am running calculates the Kretschmann scalar of some spacetime: the K. scalar is the square of the curvature tensor which has 256 components, so the number of terms in the calculation quickly explodes: what I mean is that changing my script won't solve my problem.

Comment: @K7AAY It is not a script to compile the app

Comment: Is this on a 32 bit or 64 bit system?  How much memory do you have and how much swap have you made?  Do you have an estimate of how much memory/storage is needed for your problem?

Comment: @ubfan1 64 bit, 8 Gb RAM 16 Gb swap. I have no idea of how much memory is needed

Comment: Adding swap is easy and relatively cheap, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041024/is-there-a-maximum-size-at-which-a-swap-file-can-function but without a theoretical knowledge of how the algorithm scales, anything you try may still be too small.  Maybe try halfing your problem until it runs, then you'd have some idea of what the full problem takes.